# Is there a skype "engine", not GUI, for 32bit, so that one can use pidgin or alike for video-calls?

Tags: video, skype, pidgin

I just wonder, if Is there a skype "engine", not GUI, for 32bit, so that one can use pidgin or alike for video-calls? 
chromium for 32 bit exists, I can still get to skype web, see my contacts, but phone or video not working. Any work-around? Thanks! Artem

Comment: Use 64-bit. There's no workaround.

Comment: Very strange...  Thanks for answer though.

Comment: I think there never was any "engine" allowing the use of Skype services with third-party clients, ever! Let alone a 32-bit one in 2019.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia SkypeKit used to exist for third party clients, mostly for embedded devices

Answer (score 2):

The SkypeWeb plugin for Pidgin does not - at this stage - support voice/video.  It is on my TODO list to add support for it via gstreamer-webrtc

A workaround for now is to use your browser to connect to web.skype.com and change your user agent to one that supports voice/video.  This used to be limited to Google Chrome on Linux

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! The workaround you have suggested through Chrome is ot working from early March, 2019: https://itsfoss.com/google-ending-chrome-32-bit/